# Mysql table containing csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, blob, clob

I have a table NAME
It has columns Id, Full Name ,Middle Name
and I have a csv file sample.csv
What i want is in the Table Name , Middle name column should have the sample.csv file.
And if I click on that it should open the contents of the file.

I tried LOAD DATA INFILE but of no help it loads the data of csv. What i want is the file itslef.
Like in Oracle we can store images ,CLOB,BLOB

Please Help

Comment: "When I click on that" - where, in what kind of tool? mySQL is just a database engine. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: It can be using any tool. What i need is just a link to the file in mysql table

Comment: You may need to write a tool for this using a programming language. It doesn't sound like a feature of any database client that I know of

Comment: What i want is a link to the file in table instead of storing the file.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I do not know of any tool that does this automatically, and opens the CSV file on click. You may have to program it yourself. Either way, you should give much more information, like what OS this should run on